# Using TFS Integration Platform (from codeplex) to move source to new instance

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

I have a TFS 2005 server and used the TFS Integration Platform (from [codeplex](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)) to do a 1 way migration from to a new 2010 instance.  I expected the full history to come across but instead I just to a single entry that has "TFS Integration from server name" (plus some more info).

Should I expect the history?

Is the issue that I'm going from 2005 to 2010?

If it does not bring the history what is tool really doing besides a get latest on the tip and checking in??

How can I bring the full history across?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can migrate your TFS2005 to a new TFS2010 without the TFS Integration Platform.

Take a look at [this install guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2d531219-2c39-4c69-88ef-f5ae6ac18c9f&displaylang=en), there is an entry called "Scenario: Upgrading Team Foundation Server":

> You can upgrade to Team Foundation
>   Server 2010 from the following
>   releases:
>
> - Release-candidate version of Team    Foundation Server 2010
> - Beta 2 version of Team Foundation    Server 2010
> - Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team    Foundation Server with Service Pack 1 
>     (SP1)
> - Team System 2008 Team Foundation    Server
> - Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation    Server
> - Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation    Server with SP1

Following the instructions of this guide, I was able to migrate our TFS2005 server to a new TFS2010 while keeping the history, work items, etc.

Comment: Olivier is correct. Using the built-in TFS upgrade wizard is the best way to move from TFS2005 to TFS2010. You should not use the TFS Integration Platform for this.

Answer (score 1):

Oliver is correct, best practise is an upgrade scenario. However to answer your question you can use the TFS integration platform for this and will get the history however the dates will be wrong (an issue the upgrade does not suffer from)